# Contact all members of a SharePoint site

Tags: 2010, email

I am looking for an easy way to contact (email) all the members of a SharePoint site. Is this possible without custom code?

I do NOT have the ability to create distribution groups in AD, or anything like that. I am acting as an end user who has owner rights of one Team site. I have seen some third party web parts that offer a solution but I am curious if this is possible with 'out-of-box' functionality, possibly using Outlook.

I CAN go to the 'people and groups' screen and use the actions menu to email the selected members, but this screen only lists 30 members at a time so it doesn't really scale.

Thanks!

Comment: Update: We managed to create a view on the hidden user info list that let us see all the users in one screen, thus getting rid of the 30 members at a time limitation. This however does not solve the issue as the actions menu 'send email' option just generates a mailto: link which is limited to 2083 characters (in the javascript) due to URL length limitations in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be ideal, but you could create an announcements list and add immediate alerts for the required users. When you add an announcement, they will receive an email.

Comment: It seems like this is the only option, I was just hoping to get away from the alert email template as this can get lost amongst other alerts. Thanks though.

Comment: Would someone care to share instructions on how to create an announcement list?

Answer (score -1):

you can try this guide which will export user list to Excel
http://saltypc.com/?p=90

Comment: Please dont provide links as your answer, kindly follow as mentioned in the below link http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer